# Symfony dependency injection xsd bug query

Tags: php, xml, symfony, xsd

Is anyone aware of a bug in the definition?  In both my PhpStorm IDE and in OxygenXML IDE, validation is failing with the error

System ID: http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd
Main validation file: http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd
Severity: fatal
Description: Error in complex type container: Ambiguous content model, there are two  wildcards that match overlapping sets of namespaces
Start location: 20:0

This appears to be caused by a duplicate entry for the container definition

at lines 27 and 31

The net result is that parsing a DI XML file fails

Comment: Bug is when code not working as expected, not the shitty xml schema rules.

Comment: Well @malcolm - that's useful.  For a more informed discussion see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17460.  net result is that XSD is broken, Trying to find out if there is a good reason for it to broken thus.